# SQL (in Progress Database) - How to Pivot (transpose) a table

Tags: sql, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I'm new to SQL, I've been using SQL on a Progress Database (I'm sure it uses SQL92)

**Current Output:**

[image: Current output]

**Required Output:**

[image: Required output]

Progress (or at least mine does not support `PIVOT`)

I have the following code below:

```
Select Account,

SUM(CASE WHEN AccMonth = '201703' THEN Amount END) AS "201703",
SUM(CASE WHEN AccMonth = '201702' THEN Amount END) AS "201702",
SUM(CASE WHEN AccMonth = '201701' THEN Amount END) AS "201701"


FROM

(
Select pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col" AS "Account", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col" AS "AccMonth", Sum(pub."GL_Table"."Amount_Col") AS "Amount"
FROM pub."GL_Table"
GROUP BY pub."GL_Table"."AccNum_Col", pub."GL_Table"."AccMnth_Col"
) AS tempTB


GROUP BY Account
```

Comment: Please do not post your sample data as pictures. Type out a few records worth. There are many people here who cannot help you because they cannot see the data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do aggregation.

Try this:

```
select account,
    case when accmonth = 201701 then amount end as "201701",
    case when accmonth = 201702 then amount end as "201702",
    case when accmonth = 201703 then amount end as "201703"
from your_table;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/BBNH85663)